# What is the lift to empty weight ratio of some popular modern helicopters?

Tags: helicopter, lift

What is the lift to empty weight ratio of some popular modern helicopters?

Comment: This question cannot be answered as it is. It's too broad for one thing, and you are asking for people's opinions rather than facts. Plus, I don't have any idea what you are actually asking.

Comment: Your question about pros and cons is mostly a legal and financial one, not an aviation one. We might be able to help with technical issues for your prototype, though, if you have any specific questions.

Comment: I have edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: I have edited your question further to really focus on the aviation part of the question, making it more likely you get a good answer. You can rollback my edit if you disagree.

Comment: Popular according to whom? Popular for what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

From Prouty: Helicopter Performance, Stability and Control: the example helicopter that is referenced throughout the book, to illustrate the equations used and computations made.

The rotor thrust T is a function of blade geometry and number of blades. The blade is just a rotating wing and maximum thrust is a function of the lift coefficient $C_l$ of the blade profile. Rotor thrust is also a function of rotor disc area and number of blades.

The example helicopter has the following characteristics:

- Design gross weight = 20,000 lb
- Minimum operating weight = 10,700 lb
- Main rotor radius = 30 ft
- Blade geometry: chord = 2 ft, airfoil = NACA0012, 4 blades

The average lift coefficient of the blade is computed on page 18 as $C_l$ = 0.52 at sea level, for the design gross weight. NACA 0012 has a maximum $C_l$ of 1.2, which makes the maximum rotor thrust at sea level:

$$ T_{max} = 20,000 * 1.2 / 0.52 = 46,153 lb $$

So maximum lift divided by minimum operating weight is 46,153/10,700 = 4.3

Since NACA0012 and 0015 can still be found in many helicopters, this would be the general order of magnitude for popular type helicopters. A max lift/empty weight of about 4. Further variations are due to disk loading: higher disk loading means a higher $C_l$ to lift off.