# What is the formula for estimating the maximum stationary thrust of a rotor as function of its diameter?

Tags: helicopter, performance-calculation

I am new! New to this forum and new to aviation (i normally deal with statics) so thanks in advance for beeing patient with me.
Recently i was trying to figure out **how much weight a rotor can lift as a function of the rotor diameter.**
Therefore I came across this formula.
$$
T_{rotor} =(0.5*P^2*η_{rotor}^2*η_{el}^2*π*d_{rotor}^2*ρ_{Air})^{1/3}
$$
This brings me already quite close to my goal as I now have $ Thrust = f(P^2, d^2)$. Now I tried to relate the engine power to the rotor diameter by using :

$
P=T * {rpm}$

with $ T=I *α=(0.5* m*r^2)*v_{sound}/r $

and $ {rpm}=v_{sound}/(\pi*d)$

Which leads me to
$$
P(m)=(v_{sound}^2/(4*π))*m
$$

From this calculation a few questions arise:

1. Do you think this is a good estimate (within +-15%)?
2. Is there a better formula to estimate $I_{rotor}$ than using $I_{zylinder}$?
3. Is there any formula to estimate $ m_{rotor} = f(d_{rotor})  $

I want to add  that this estimate is for a rough feasability study and not to design a rotor or aircraft. I also know that several of the values in this formulas are a function of altitude and aircraft velocity. Please dont take this into account. At the moment I am only interested in a stationary solution.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please don't forget the root, which makes thrust proportional to d$^⅔$ only, less than linear.

Comment: You lost me at the P = T * rpm. Is this T for torque? What is I and which $\alpha$ are you using, angle of attack?

Comment: The $T = I \cdot \alpha$ is the formula for determining the torque as a function of the angular acceleration, which you can also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia). This however is not the right formula to use, as it completely neglects all air drag, and only accounts for inertia. What would happen if we have a constant rpm, and thus $\alpha = 0$? We need 0 torque to drive the rotor? OP, please check where the formula comes from, and its applicability

Answer (score 1):

The dimensional approach is simple... It can be safely assumed that the lift $L$ is a function of the input power $P$, the diameter $D$ of the rotor and the air density $\rho$.

Thus, $L = f(P,D,\rho)$

where $f$ is a function to be determined.

From dimensional analysis, the lift $L$ can be easily derived:

The variables are Lift $L$, dimensions $MLT^{–2}$; Power $P$, dimensions  $ML^2T^{–3}$; Rotor diameter $D$, dimensions $L$ and air density $\rho$, dimensions $ML^{–3}$

The variables form a non-dimensional product $k$

$k = L^a\cdot P^b\cdot D^c\cdot \rho^d$  where $a,b,c,d$ are numbers to be determined.

Let’s form now a parallel product $k^*$ with the dimensions:

$k^* = (MLT^{–2})^a  (ML^2T^{–3})^b  (L)^c (ML^{–3})^d$

Clearly, $k^* = M^0 L^0 T^0$... We now take the exponents for each dimension:

$a  + b + d = 0 \\
a + 2b + c – 3d = 0 \\
–2a – 3b = 0$

We make $a = 1$, since $L$ is the variable we’re going to solve for.

$b = –2/3 \\ 
d = –1/3 \\
c = –2/3$

Then,

$k = L^a\cdot P^b\cdot D^c\cdot \rho^d \rightarrow  k = L\cdot P^{–2/3}\cdot D^{–2/3}\cdot \rho^{–1/3}$

Solving for $L$

$L = k\cdot P^{2/3}\cdot D^{2/3}\cdot \rho^{1/3}$

where $k$ is a constant to be determined...

Comment: How is lift proportional to $\rho^{1/3}$? In the equation $T = C_T \cdot \rho \cdot A \cdot (\Omega \cdot R)^2$ the rotor thrust is proportional to $\rho^1$

Comment: @Koyovis. The dimensional derivation is correct. Hence, rho *must* have the exponent 1/3...

Comment: @Koyovis In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_loading#Momentum_theory you'll find an expression for the power required in hover as a function of the thrust, disk area, and air density. Solving that expression for thrust, you'll see that rho appears with the exponent 1/3...

Comment: For the power, yes. But we're trying to find thrust as a function of blade radius.

Comment: @Koyovis  If you solve that expression for thrust, you'll find that rho has the exponent 1/3, exactly as when derived by the dimensional method.

Answer (score 1):

No the equation in your question is not useable. However there are tabulations of existing helicopters that provide a better method.

Maximum stationary thrust as a function of the rotor diameter. What you are looking for is related to the disk loading of a helicopter: when in hover, the rotor thrust equals weight. Heavier helicopters must unfortunately use higher disk loading, a feature dictated by the [Square-Cube law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square%E2%80%93cube_law). From Helicopter Aerodynamics by J. Gordon Leishman:

[image]

This is a direct relation between blade radius and max gross weight, no need to introduce the installed power etc into it. Note that the trend line is proportional to $W^{1/3}$.

When in hover at max gross weight, there is some more lift in reserve. How much depends on the disk loading and the air density. [In another question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/44535/21091) we came to an estimation of twice the max gross weight at sea level valid for the disk loading of the Prouty example helicopter = 7.1 lb/ft$^2$ / rotor radius of 30 ft / max gross weight of 20,000 lb. For heavier helicopters the disk loading is higher, and this lift reserve reduces with disk loading and gross weight.

[image]

The above is a digitised plot of the line in Leishmans fig 6.3 in metric units, weight in N and radius in m. Lift in the hover is proportional to the square of the rotor radius - which makes sense, proportional to the rotor disk area as in equation:

$$T = C_T \cdot \rho \cdot A \cdot {V_{tip}}^2$$

As the rotor radius gets larger it turns slower, to prevent the blade tip from exceeding the critical Mach number.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your expalantions. The graphs are very helpful and exactly what i am looking for. The lower graph is from Leishmans "Principles of Helicopter Aerodynamics"?

Comment: The upper graph was used as a baseline. It is on a logarithmic scale, I digitised it, converted to metric and plotted on a linear scale.

Comment: I see :) Thanks again