# Is this equation for propeller thrust correct?

Tags: aircraft-design, propeller

From dimensional considerations, and assuming that the power $P$ applied to a propeller of diameter $D$ moving at an axial speed $V$ is 100% converted to the acceleration of a mass of air with density $rho$, I have arrived to the following expression for the thrust $F$:

$F=k(P·rho·V)^{1/2}·D$

where $k$ is a non-dimensional constant.

Is that expression basically correct? I'm now editing to include below the derivation, a bit long...

We have a propeller with a diameter $D$, absorbing a power $P$ when moving at an axial velocity $V$ in air of density $\rho$. Let’s assume that there exists a function f such that the thrust $F$ of the propeller is:

$F = f(P,D,V,\rho)$

The variables are thrust $F$, dimensions $MLT^{–2}$; Power $P$, dimensions    $ML^2T^{–3}$; prop diameter $D$, dimensions $L$ and air density $\rho$, dimensions $ML^{–3}$

Five variables are too much. The system can’t be solved unless we have four, one dependent and  tree independent…  So, in place of $V$ and $D$, we take the volume $W$ swept by the spinning propeller in the unit of time, dimensions $L^{3}T^{–1}$

$W = π/4 · D^{2} · V$

There is an non-dimensional constant $k$ such that:

$k = F^a\cdot P^b\cdot \rho^c \cdot W^d$ where $a,b,c,d$ are numbers to be determined.

Switching to the dimensions:

$M^0 L^0 T^0 = (MLT^{–2})^a  (ML^2T^{–3})^b  (ML^{–3})^c (L^3 T^{–1})^d$

Then, the system is:

$0 = a + b + c\\
0 = a + 2b –3c + 3d \\
0 = –2a –3b –d$

$F$ is the dependent variable, so we make a=1

Solving the system:

$b = –1/2 \\ 
d = –1/2 \\
c = –1/2$

Inserting in 
$k = F^a\cdot P^b\cdot \rho^c \cdot W^d$ where $a,b,c,d$
the values of the exponents, and solving for $F$,

$F = k\cdot P^{1/2}\cdot \rho^{1/2} \cdot W^{1/2}$

But $W = π/4 · D^{2} · V$

Now $k$ may absorb the constant π/4, and we get:

$F = k\cdot P^{1/2}\cdot \rho^{1/2} \cdot V^{1/2}\cdot D$

Comment: this seems related, and Peter's answer seem to contain what you need: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8819/is-there-any-equation-to-bind-velocity-thrust-and-power?rq=1

Comment: How did you calculate the exponents? I can identify four unknown exponents, but only three dimesional equations.

Comment: @Federico In the –quite likely– case that Kämpf's answer is right, the expression I've derived is probably wrong...

Comment: @Gypaets Give me some time, and I will write down the derivation...

Comment: You already wrote the derivation for the static case (as in Peter's answer) in this question https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/44654/8749. The point in this question is if there is a thrust dependency on the speed $V$ or not.

Comment: @Gypaets Yes, but in this case there's an axial speed $V$, hence it's different...

Comment: @Gypaets  Derivation included...

Comment: @xxavier.  Thrust is caused by a change in momentum, or/and an increase in static pressure, acting over an area. So, for a gas turbine, Net thrust (FN) = M x  (Ve - Va) / g + Ae x (Pse - Pamb). Va is the aircraft velocity, Ve is the exhaust velocity. The physics is the same for a prop, but when the flow is subsonic, Pse = Pamb. So, you are left with the first term, and your velocity term should be a change in velocity, of the mass flow going through the prop. This confers with the general form of Peter's answer.

Comment: @Penguin  A dimensional derivation is independent of the underlying physical facts. The variables have to be chosen well, but that's all... The velocity term that I consider is not that of the moving air mass, but the axial velocity of the prop, with respect to the distant mass of air at rest.

Comment: @xxavier. Fully understand the dimensional analysis approach. But you *can* use DA *and* an understanding of the physics to arrive an equation which is dimensional correct *and* physically correct. The two are not mutually exclusive. And... your question *is* asking if your equation is correct, so I am answering that by showing one of the errors.

Comment: @Penguin Yes, you are right pointing out that the physical, underlying reality should not be ignored, but what I want is a derivation of thrust as a function of power absorbed, prop diameter and **prop axial velocity** with respect to distant, calm air; and not to the velocity imparted by the prop to the air mass...

Comment: @xxavier. OK, if that's a constraint you want to include, fair enough. A pity no one has answered yet, I think it's actually one of the more technically interesting and well thought out questions for quite a while.

Comment: @xxavier What is prop axial velocity exactly ? Do you mean  flight velocity V0 or air axial velocity in stream tube (Momentum + actuator disk theory) at prop position ?

Comment: @Acsed I mean flight velocity...

Comment: @xxavier: then, I do not really like the use of your variable « W » which is not the volumetric flow through the propeller. 

Moreover, even if your derivation seems correct, why your dimension analysing did not include rotational speed (N) or torque (T) ? Commonly, Thrust and Power are related by overall prop efficiency with « eta = F V0 / Pw » where Power is given by both N and T. Maybe you should try another derivation with one more variable leading to 2 or 3 dimensionless numbers.

Comment: @Acsed Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try doing as you say...

Answer (score 1):

From the comments:`what I want is a derivation of thrust as a function of power absorbed, prop diameter and prop axial velocity..`

- Power absorbed $P$ is engine torque  times prop angular velocity $\omega$: $P =  \cdot \omega \tag{1}$.
- Prop axial velocity at the tip $V_t =\omega \cdot D \tag{2}$

$P$ is the power applied in the axial direction, while thrust is generated in the direction perpendicular to the propeller plane - there must be some function describing the relationship between the forces in both directions. This function would be one describing efficiency and losses, since the primary force application is the engine torque and the thrust is the net resulting force.

If the goal is like is stated in OP `...propeller of diameter  moving at an axial speed  is 100% converted to the acceleration of a mass of air...` this means that there are no losses, and we can use the simple impulse theory of the magic disk. This is comprehensively explained in [this post](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-calculate-the-lift-of-a-helicopter-in-hover), which results in the following equation between thrust and power:

$$P = \sqrt{\frac{F^3}{2\rho A}} \tag{3}$$

If we want $V_t$ in there we need to substitute (1) and (2):

$$\frac { \cdot V_t}{D} = \sqrt{\frac{F^3}{2\rho A}} \tag{4}$$

Since A = propeller disk area = $\frac {\pi}{4} \cdot D^2$, (4) further boils down to:

$$F^{3/2} = k \cdot  \cdot V_t \cdot \rho^{1/2} \tag{5}$$

Note that (3) contains $P$ but no $V_t$, while (5) contains $V_t$ but no P. We could lump the motor torque into the force $F$ dimension, but all my engineering genes scream to **not** do that because of the origin and effect relationship: no engine torque, no net thrust.

Both (3) and (5) contain $\rho$, which is a must considering that the thrust is obtained by acceleration of a mass of air. The mass flow dimension can disappear into a force dimension as well when multiplied by a velocity, for instance a propeller tip velocity...

[This answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/67232/21091) shows the relationship between thrust and power of a helicopter rotor in the hover (and therefore of a propeller) using modified momentum theory with losses:

$$C_P = \frac{\kappa \cdot {C_T}^{3/2}}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\sigma \cdot {C_D}_0}{8}$$

with $\kappa$ = loss factor and $\sigma$ = blade solidity. So the exponent of the function (induced power) vs. (thrust) is 3/2. Also, there is an additional term that the dimensional analysis cannot catch, which is power required in the propeller plane.

Comment: I see a problem: Equation (3) is derived from momentum considerations for the case of static thrust. that's an special case, since, in that condition, the angles of attack 'seen' by the blades are much greater than the angle 'seen' by the blades when there is a significant axial velocity of the prop disk...